# Reduce "code" memory usage

Tags: android, memory-management, android-monitor

I'm monitoring the memory usage of my `Android application` through the [Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler.html) and I see that my app is using more than 30MB of RAM for the `code`. But I don't have a clue on how to reduce the memory used by this `code`.

Quoting the android documentation:

> Code: Memory that your app uses for code and resources, such as dex bytecode, optimized or compiled dex code, .so libraries, and fonts.

- How could we reduce the `dex code`of the application?
- What are `.so Libraries` and what could I do to reduce the impact of such libraries?
- Is their anything else I could do to reduce this memory usage?

Thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce `the dex code` just use less libraries. Sometimes it is sufficient to attach only some parts of a framework. Check all your `build.gradle` files for unneeded inclusions.

`.so libraries` are native dynamically linked libraries, usually written in C or C++ which can be used in Android application, see [NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html).

Comment: is there any efficient way to investigate which exact libraries or app classes consume more dex code than others?

Comment: you can't do it with Jetpack Compose, there are still a lot of libraries just from Google itself, also Retrofit, Hilt, Firebase and many other necessary libraries without you can't just develop and publish the app

Comment: Just create a simple app adding these libraries only and sending a single network request for example, you will be surprised how small it is